# Continuum spectrum of the multiplication operator in $C([a,b])$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=C([a, b])$ and fix $m \in X$.

Define the multiplication operator $T: X \rightarrow X$ by
$$
(T f)(x):=m(x) \cdot f(x) \text { for } x \in[a, b] .
$$

I have to determine $\sigma_p(T), \sigma_c(T)$, and $\sigma_r(T)$.

After some calculations I arrived that $\sigma(T)=Ran(m)$.

My question takes as a focus the situation where $m(x) \ne \lambda$ for some $x \in [a,b]$.

What I am having trouble analysing is $\sigma_c(T)$ because in this problem one typically constructs the sequence of functions

$$
f_n = \frac{1}{m(x)-\lambda} f \chi_{[a,b]\setminus \big (\bigcup_{x_0 \in A}  B_{\frac{1}  {n}}(x_0) \big)}
$$

where $A$ is the zero set of $m$ in $[a,b]$ to prove that $Ran(T-\lambda I)$ is dense in $C([a,b])$.

The problem is that this sequence is not everywhere continuous, i.e $f_n \notin C([a,b])$ and so we cannot use this sequence to prove that $Ran(T-\lambda I)$ is dense in $C([a,b])$, however I am inclined to believe that $Ran(T-\lambda I)$ is dense for $\lambda \in Ran(m)$.

Any resolutions or suggestions of sequences would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the topology, so I'll assume that you are using the usual choice of considering $\|f\|_\infty=\max\{|f(t)|:\ t\in[a,b]\}$.

The assumption is that $\lambda\in\operatorname{Ran}m$ and $\lambda\not\in\sigma_p(T)$. We have $\lambda=m(x_1)$ for some $x_1\in[a,b]$. Then, for any $h\in C[a,b]$,
$$
[(T-\lambda)h](x_1)=(m(x_1)-\lambda)h(x_1)=0. 
$$
So if $g\in C[a,b]$ satisfies $g(x_1)=1$, we get
$$
\|(T-\lambda)h-g\|_\infty\geq|(T-\lambda )h(x_1)-g(x_1)|=1.
$$
So $\operatorname{Ran}(T-\lambda)$ cannot be dense. Thus $\sigma_c(T)=\varnothing$.